# Offline database can't be restored: Exclusive access could not be obtained

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharepoint, sql

I'm practicing a SharePoint 2010 to 2013 migration and having trouble restoring a database. After backing up a database on a SP2010/SQL 2008 server, I'm trying to restore it to a database I've freshly created on my SP2013/SQL 2012 server.

Though the UI, I've taken the destination database offline. I select the `.bak` file, select my destination database, and attempt the restoration. I get an error: `Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.`

Why is this happening? I've taken the database offline, I don't see how it could possibly be in use.

In the restoration window, I've tried going to Options and selecting `Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)` as well as `Close existing connections to destination database`.

Still the same error message. How do I get past this error?

Comment: Call me stupid but why would you restore the database to an existing database? Why not restore it to a new database?

Answer (score 4):

Are you the person who is currently using the database?  :)

Try running this before you do the restore:

```
USE master
Go
ALTER DATABASE YourDB
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

That should kick everyone off.  If not, you're definitely the person currently using the database.  Close any SSMS windows using the database and run:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDB
SET offline
```

Comment: I am unquestionably the only person to be using the server and the database. I have SSMS open just to open the restoration window. Also, my database is already offline. Anyway, the issue persists after using your script to set it to Single User.

Comment: I ran through the commands on a DB of my own to double-check, and until I closed the SSMS window where I'd accessed my test DB, the restore failed as "in use."  This session didn't show up in sp_WhoIsActive, sp_who, or sp_who2, but I was still blocked.  Bring the DB back online and close all SSMS windows and try again and see if that does the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm unsure how I can restore the database without using SSMS...

Comment: Close any open windows you have and create a new one that's not connected to that database.  (It's not your default login database, is it?)  Then run the restore.

Comment: I'm unclear on your instructions. I've tried opening up the restoration window and disconnecting from the server in SSMS then running the restore... still the same issue.

Comment: Open SSMS.  If it's already open, close any query windows you have open so you're looking at blank default SSMS.  Connect to the server.  Make sure that you are connected to master as your DB.  Click new query.  Paste your version of "RESTORE DATABASE [YourDB] FROM  DISK = N'C:\backups\YourDB.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO" into the new, fresh, never touched your DB query window.

Comment: Couldn't get that to work: `The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'WSS_Content_Migration' database.`. Here's something interesting: In the backup window, I tried specifying a new database name. The SAME ERROR pops up. How is this possible with a database that doesn't even exist yet!?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12377/discussion-between-katherine-villyard-and-tnw)

Comment: Would you have a moment to continue our discussion from yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

A number of issues here and things I didn't mention which were part of the problem. This was a database backup taken from a SQL 2008 instance and being restored on a SQL 2012 instance. This bit of T-SQL finally did it:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [WSS_Content_Migrated] 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL\MSSQL\Backup\WSS_Content.bak' WITH 
MOVE 'WSS_Content' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL\MSSQL\Backup\WSS_Content.mdf',
MOVE 'WSS_Content_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL\MSSQL\Backup\WSS_Content.ldf'
, REPLACE
```